# Very simple question about operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Vector2
{
    int x = -500, y = -1000;
    Vector2(int x, int y) : x{x}, y{y} {}
    Vector2 operator+(const Vector2& vec)
    {
        return Vector2(x + vec.x, y + vec.y);
    }    
};

int main()
{

    Vector2 vec1(10, 20);
    Vector2 vec2(15, 30);
    //vec3 should be 25,50;
    Vector2 result = vec1 + vec2;
    cout << result.x << ", ";
    cout << result.y;
}
```

I just want to know exactly what happens when I overload an operator.

For example here I overload the + operator for this Vector2 class.How exactly does this work?

Is it like once the `+` is seen it kind of just saves the object to the left of the operator and the parameter is the object on the right? By saves the object to the left of the operator I mean like does it just kind of refer to `vec1.x` when I refer to `x`?

It just automatically does that because it's on the left side of the operator? And the right side is always going to be the parameter.

Is that how it works?

Comment: `vec1 + vec2` is syntactic sugar for `vec1.operator+(vec2)`, so `this` (which is optional in front of `x` and `y`) will be a pointer to `vec1` and `vec` will be a reference to `vec2`.

Answer (score 3):

If you overload an operator inside the class it will behave like a member-function. So `x` will refer to `this->x` just like in any member functions. If the compiler sees an `a+b` expression with types `A` and `B` it will search for `A::operator+((const)B(&)) (const)` or `operator+((const)A(&),(const)B(&))`.